# c# wpf multiple dictionaries to datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, dictionary, datagrid

I have multiple dictionaries. Each of them contains the same keys, just with different values. I am using them for translations. They are dynamically created..

So, it looks something like this:

DictionaryEng:
first_page_name = "First page"
second_page_name = "Second page"

DictionaryRu:
first_page_name = "Первая страница"
second_page_name = "Вторая страница"

I would like this informations to be shown in DataGrid or, so user can change the values. It should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c1IY.jpg), end values to be editable.

What's the best practice to do this?

Comment: do you know about MVVM? Is it ok for you if I show you an example assuming that you have a ViewModelBase?

Comment: Problem is that the objects in Dictionary are dynamically created with JSON deserializer...so, I don't have idea what Key or Value values will be...or, is there a way with MVVM to achieve this?

Comment: Ok, I'll mock up the creation of the dictionary with a stub function called in the vm c.tor

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to bind the DataGrid to a Collection

```
    <DataGrid 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Lines}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"
```

I'll mock up the creation of the dictionary with stub functions called in the ViewModel c.tor

```
public class MyVM : ViewModelBase
{
    public MyVM()
    {
        Line.DictionaryEng = Line.DictionaryEngStub();
        Line.DictionaryRu = Line.DictionaryRuStub();
        lines = new ObservableCollection<Line>(Line.DictionaryEng.Keys.Select(k => new Line() { KeyWord = k }));
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Line> lines;
    public ObservableCollection<Line> Lines
    {
        get { return lines;  }
        set
        {
            lines = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Lines");
        }
    }
}
```

where the underlying class is defined as follows

```
public class Line : ViewModelBase
{
    internal static Dictionary<string, string> DictionaryEngStub()
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "first_page_name ","First page" },
            { "second_page_name  ","Second page" }
        };
    }
    internal static Dictionary<string, string> DictionaryRuStub()
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"first_page_name ","Первая страница" },
            {"second_page_name  ","Вторая страница" }
        };
    }
    internal static Dictionary<string, string> DictionaryEng = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    internal static Dictionary<string, string> DictionaryRu = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    private string keyWord; 
    public string KeyWord
    {
        get { return keyWord;  }
        set
        {
            keyWord = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("keyWord");
        }
    }
    public string EnglishWord {
       get
        {
            string english;
            if (DictionaryEng.TryGetValue(keyWord ?? "", out english))
            {
                return english;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    public string RussianhWord
    {
        get
        {
            string russian;
            if (DictionaryRu.TryGetValue(keyWord ?? "", out russian))
            {
                return russian;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that the translations have only a getter to retrieve the string from the dictionary.
You can easily make them editable by adding a setter to save the new translation into a persistence layer. Furthermore, English and Russian dictionaries are generic enough to be renamed as from/to dictionaries. Once the user selects a language in another combobox, you can reset the dictionary accordingly.
Since I have a stub here, the setter does not make much sense, but just to give you and idea...

```
    private string englishSaved;
    public string EnglishWord {
       get
        {
            if (englishSaved != null)
            {
                return englishSaved;
            }
            string english;
            if (DictionaryEng.TryGetValue(keyWord ?? "", out english))
            {
                return english;
            }
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            englishSaved = value; //save the new translation into a persistence layer
        }
    }
```

Comment: How will user change the values if there are only getters? And, another thing, I also don't know what languages user will choose...so, he can choose english, russian, serbian...

Comment: As I have written, you simply add the setter to where you want to save the new values. And it's easy to add another combobox with the user selected language binding. At this point your question is vague and incomplete